# Compute 2d velocity field with given curl and zero divergence

Tags: vorticity, divergence-free

Given $\omega$ I want to compute the vector $q=(u,v)$ such that
$$
v_x - u_y = \omega, \qquad u_x + v_y = 0, \qquad \textrm{in } \Omega
$$
and
$$
u n_x + v n_y = 0, \qquad \textrm{on } \partial\Omega
$$
I am looking for a finite element method to find such a vector field.

I can introduce a stream function $\psi$ such that
$$
\Delta\psi = -\omega
$$
and then $(u,v) = (\psi_y, -\psi_x)$. Solving this numerically I would obtain $\psi^h \in P_k$ but then $(u^h, v^h) = (\psi_y^h, -\psi_x^h)$ will not be globally divergence-free, i.e., normal component of velocity will not be continuous across the elements when using $C^0$ elements.

So I want to obtain a globally divergence-free vector field with specified curl.

**Projection to Raviart-Thomas space**

I obtain $\psi^h \in P_k$ and then project to $RT_k$: find $q^h \in RT_k$ such that
$$
\int_\Omega q^h \cdot w dx = \int_\Omega (\psi^h_y, -\psi^h_x) \cdot w dx, \qquad \forall w \in RT_k
$$
I can check that the resulting $q^h$ indeed has zero divergence and converges with error $O(h^k)$ which seems less than optimal. I don't know how to prove these things but I guess this must already be published somewhere. I am looking for some reference on this sort of projection.

But I am also interested to know if we can compute $q$ without using a stream-function.

Comment: What do you know about $\omega$? Does it have any exploitable structure?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth $\omega$ is a scalar for me and I dont know anything more about this function.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with FEM as I am with FVM and FDM, but I see no issue with using streamfunction with FDM. Is this because of non-orthogonal elements or something?

Comment: I have to use the velocity within a finite element method to solve another PDE. Hence I am looking for a finite element method to find the velocity also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the stream function actually gives a globally divergence-free solution. So the statement in my question was not correct.

Solve
$$
\Delta \psi^h = -\omega
$$
using $C^0$ elements and Galerkin method. Then compute
$$
(u^h, v^h) = (\psi_y^h, -\psi_x^h)
$$
The normal component of velocity on cell faces is
$$
u^h n_x + v^h n_y = \psi_y^h n_x - \psi_x^h n_y = \textrm{tangential derivative of } \psi^h
$$
But since $\psi^h$ is continuous, its tangential derivative on a face has the same value whether we evaluate it from one side or the other.